# Unir dos ficheros java entremezclados con BufferedWriter

Tags: java

estoy intentando hacer un programa que le introduces 2 rutas de lectura y 1 donde se va a escribir los 2 textos entremezclados, el caso que lo he hecho con un contador, pero no consigo que lea más de la linea 1 de la primera ruta.

Adjunto.

Texto a (a.txt):

```
Hola
esto
es
una
prueba
me
llamo
Enrique
```

Texto b (b.txt):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Ejercicio:

```
/*
 * Crea un programa que solicita 3 ficheros de texto
 *  (2 de lectura y 1 de escritura), y escriba en el fichero de escritura el contenido de fichero de texto, 
 * de forma alternativa (1 línea de cada fichero). El contenido final debe 
 * ser el de ambos ficheros de lectura entremezcladas las líneas.
 * 
 * 
 * */

package primeraevaluacion;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class P03_tarea3ej2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fichero1;
        String fichero2;
        String fichero3;
        boolean correcto = false;
        File f1 = null;
        File f2 = null;
        String linea1;
        String linea2;
        int cnt=1;
        
        System.out.println("En la primera y segunda ruta introduzca ficheros de lectura, en la última ruta, donde quieres que se escriban");
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        
        
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca ruta fichero 1 (lectura)");
            fichero1 = Entrada.cadena();
            f1 = new File(fichero1);
            
        if (!f1.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("La ruta que se ha introducido no existe, introduzcalo de nuevo");
            correcto=false;
        } else {
            correcto=true;
        }
        
        
        } while (!correcto);
        
        correcto=false;
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca ruta fichero 2 (lectura)");
            fichero2 = Entrada.cadena();
            f2 = new File(fichero2);
            
        if (!f2.isFile()) {
            System.out.println("La ruta que se ha introducido no existe, introduzcalo de nuevo");
            correcto=false;
        } else {
            correcto=true;
        }
        
    
        } while (!correcto);
        
    
        
        
        System.out.println("Introduzca ruta fichero 3 (donde se va a escribir)");
        fichero3= Entrada.cadena();
        
        File f3 = new File(fichero3);
        
        BufferedWriter nf3 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f3));
        BufferedReader bf1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));
        BufferedReader bf2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f2));
        
        while ((linea1 = bf1.readLine())!= null) {
            while ((linea2=bf2.readLine())!=null) {
                
                if (cnt%2!=0) {
                    nf3.write(linea2+"\n");
                    
                }
                
                cnt++;
            
                }
    
            }
        
        bf1.close();
        bf2.close();
        nf3.close();
        
        System.out.println("Actualice el proyecto y mire el archivo: "+fichero3);
        
    }

}
```

Clase entrada (esta no hace falta mirarla, esta es para recoger la información introducida, pero la dejo porque hay gente que la pide)

```
package utilidades;
import java.io.*;

public class Entrada {
    static String inicializar() {
        String buzon = "";
        InputStreamReader flujo = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(flujo);
        try {
            buzon = teclado.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.append("Entrada incorrecta)");
        }
        return buzon;
    }

    public static int entero() {
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(inicializar());
        return valor;
    }
    
    public static int entero(String mensaje) {
        int n=0;
        boolean correcto;
        do {
            correcto=true;
            System.out.print(mensaje);
            try {
                n=entero();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("NÃºmero incorrecto. IntrodÃºzcalo de nuevo.");
                correcto=false;
            }
        }while(!correcto);
        return n;
    }

    public static double real() {
        double valor = Double.parseDouble(inicializar());
        return valor;
    }
    
    public static double real(String mensaje) {
        double n=0;
        boolean correcto;
        do {
            correcto=true;
            System.out.print(mensaje);
            try {
                n=real();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("NÃºmero incorrecto. IntrodÃºzcalo de nuevo.");
                correcto=false;
            }
        }while(!correcto);
        return n;
    }

    public static String cadena() {
        String valor = inicializar();
        return valor;
    }

    public static char caracter() {
        String valor = inicializar();
        return valor.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Resultado erroneo que me da: ruta que le digo (c.txt):

```
1
Hola
3
Hola
5
Hola
7
Hola
9
Hola
```

He buscado en un montón de sitios y no lo resuelvo, no doy con la forma, esto es el último sitio donde pregunto, gracias si alguien me ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede apreciar que solo estas agregando los datos al f3 cuando el contador es impar
pero que sucede cuando el contador es par??

```
 if (cnt%2!=0) {
        nf3.write(linea2+"\n");     
                }
```

Respuesta:

```
 int cnt=0;//el contador inicia en0
//usamos el operador logico AND en un solo while
    while ((linea1 = bf1.readLine())!= null&&(linea2=bf2.readLine())!=null) {
    
                   if (cnt%2!=0) {
                   //cuando el contador es impar 
                   //agregas tanto los valores de a y b o visceversa 
                        nf3.write(linea2+"\n");
                        nf3.write(linea1+"\n");
                             
                    }else{
                   //cuando es par
                        nf3.write(linea2+"\n");
                        nf3.write(linea1+"\n");
                       
                    }
                    cnt++;
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, es que como estaba editando todo el rato se me borró el else, justo habia pensado en un and así, pero no se si servirá, lo que quería hacer con el contador era que si es par por ejmplo que escribiera la linea 1 y si es impar la linea 2, pero no se por qué tú pones en las 2 condiciones 2 veces las cosas, un saludo

Comment: ten presente que son dos archivos por eso debes poner los dos el par de a salto de linea par de b salto de linea  impar de a salto de linea impar de b... y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Luego hay algo que me he fijado y es que no coje el 9 y el 10? las 2 lineas que faltan del archivo b, es por alguna razón?

Comment: Recuerda que ambas líneas de lectura debes ser diferentes a null como  a tiene 8 líneas y b 10 líneas a tebdra 2 líneas que son null y por eso no jalara el 9 y 10